# How to access a property value inside JsonResponse Object in PHP or Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm doing a POST using Ajax and my Server is getting the data just fine. However, I'm struggling to access the value the user sent. In simple words how can I access the value of "user" (tom) ?. Anyone could get me on the right track please. Thank you in advance. Here's my JsonResponse object:

```
[2016-10-22 05:10:49] local.INFO: From Ajax: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse Object
(
[data:protected] => {"user":"Tom","_token":"uRZJBVHH3worhjX4Ul6WlnJC1JYh3EVMNWob7Azr"}
[callback:protected] => 
[encodingOptions:protected] => 0
[headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object
    (
        [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array
            (
                [no-cache] => 1
            )

        [cookies:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [headerNames:protected] => Array
            (
                [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                [content-type] => Content-Type
            )

        [headers:protected] => Array
            (
                [cache-control] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => no-cache
                    )

                [content-type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => application/json
                    )

            )

        [cacheControl:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[content:protected] =>     {"user":"Tom","_token":"uRZJBVHH3worhjX4Ul6WlnJC1JYh3EVMNWob7Azr"}
[version:protected] => 1.0
[statusCode:protected] => 200
[statusText:protected] => OK
[charset:protected] => 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my issue and I'm going to share it in case someone needs it.
So the way I was getting the JsonObjec was by doing this in Routes.php:

```
Route::post('/register', function(){
if(Request::ajax()){
    Log::info('From Ajax: ' . print_r(Response::json(Request::all()), true));
    
    return var_dump(Response::json(Request::all()));
} 
});
```

**But instead I did this to actually access the value of user (Tom).**

```
$somevar = (Request::all());
Log::info('From Ajax: ' . print_r($somevar["user"], true));
```

This solve my issue. Hope it helps anyone out there!

Answer (score 50):

Using Laravel the data can also be accessed using illuminate `getData()` method.

```
$someVar->getData();
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html#method_getData

Comment: simple but save my live

Answer (score 1):

With Laravel you can access to JSON data same way as regular variables. In your case you need something like:

```
$username = $request->get('user');
```

Comment: This doesn't apply to the JsonObject I get in my server. I need to find a way another to access the value of user.

Comment: @HenryDev
Hmm.. What about `content()` method? https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html

Answer (score 1):

hope not 'too late to the party'. Have you tried calling the function getData() before accessing the property.
i.e. $jsonObject->getData()->firstName;